# Oracle Matrix for AL32UTF8 characterset

Tags: oracle, nls, codepages

Using the DUMP command within Oracle, it produces the following :

```
 SQL> select dump(field1, 1016) from test_nls;
 Typ=1 Len=8 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: c3,bd,c3,a3,c3,a1,c3,b6
```

Is there a AL32UTF8 matrix of sort out there where I can compare the two bytes c3 bd, c3 a3, c3 a1, and c3 b6 with the matrix to see the expected character then compare it with the character within the database to confirm it is indeed correct?

Comment: Looks like 4 characters, 8 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A web search for "utf8 lookup" yielded a number of options. This one ...

[UTF-8 encoding table and Unicode characters](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)

presents a table of characters and their encodings, which seems close to the "matrix" you seek.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually found this URL as well shortly afterward : http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm